# Publish Code Builds/Releases on a Git Branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, release

I am the sole developer on a corporate repository. It is hosted on BitBucket, which I don't believe to have the `Releases` feature I've seen on GitHub. I'm looking to make a first release of the software, but users don't need access to the code, just an executable. (It's not a security risk, just a convenience factor - no point in copying down 50 development files used for building.)

I've heard that Bitbucket has a Downloads feature, but I don't see that's it's enabled in my repo. I am currently thinking through maintaining a `Stable` branch that contains only the two files users will need.

1. How can I structure this new branch and maintain it in the future? (new `.gitignore`? Local merges, best practices with tagging, etc.)
2. Is the `Stable` branch approach misguided? Do I need to just point to an external storage?
   2.1 The binaries to be published are plenty small enough for git (~`5MB`).
   2.2  Additionally, the repo is also comparatively small (~`100MB`), so copying it isn't unreasonable, just unnecessary.

Comment: Bitbucket does have a "downloads" section https://bitbucket.org/name-of-user/repo-name/downloads/

Comment: Great point - is that necessarily available when self-hosting? I may be missing a menu button to get there, but bitbucket.company.com/projects/PROJ/repos/REPO/downloads is not a valid link. (Nor are close relatives of that)